# Expand column width for exported excel

Tags: php, excel, magento

I am doing an excel export from Magento. I wish to auto resize the column. Here is my code that I tried,

```
public function exportOrders($orders)
{
$fileName = 'order_export_'.date("Ymd_His").'.csv';
$fp = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir('export').'/'.$fileName, 'w');

$this->writeHeadRow($fp);
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order);
    $this->writeOrder($order, $fp);
}

for($i = $fromCol; $i !== $toCol; $i++) {
    $calculatedWidth = $sheet->getColumnDimension($i)->getWidth();
    $sheet->getColumnDimension($i)->setWidth((int) $calculatedWidth * 2);
}

fclose($fp);

return $fileName;
}
```

It does not seem to work.

Comment: 1. You are exporting a `.csv` and not a excel `.xls` file. 2. Where is `$sheet` define

Comment: Is this part of a PHPExcel plug-in for Magento? (e.g. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/php-excel-library.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PhpExcel Library

// this extenstion using PhpExcel Lib [Perfect Excel Export - Management Report](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/perfect-excel-export-management-report.html)
then

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);

hope this help you